Printer add Dialogbox freeze and Hanged in RDS 2019
We have RDS 2019 single server.
Whenever we add any Network printer for example Start > Run > type > \PrinterServer\  > Right click on any Printer select Add or connect then nothing happens even click many times.
Also If we go to control -> Click on Add Printer -> Select any Network Printer -> Then it stuck on connecting and nothing happens.
We already tried below steps

Tried from different users Profiles including local and domain and non domain.

Network Printers and RDS 2019 servers are on Same network and same Office.

Checked from other RDS 2019 server and Printers are working fine from there.

Ran sfc and DISM to repair on RDS 2019 and disabled local Windows firewall.

This happens to all shared printers and not single Printer.

All Printer related GPO settings are "Not Configured"


Any advise will be highly apricated why Dialog box freeze or not responding
